# Symfony 5 - Rendering multiple choice field from different entities in an app without relationships defined in the Entity creation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a question, im trying to get a multiple choice field from a different entity than the main form entity to work.

I have more than 1 table in my database, and the main table, lets call it "person" requires that the form rendering includes several multiple options from different entities than its own. lets just add 2 for example, they are "language" and "skills", where Language its its own entity, and can have several languages in it, and skills is the same, so when you add a new Person, the form should render the "languages" and "skills" from its respective tables, I am not using a relational entity, as this is a quick mvp that I gota finish very fast, so I decided to go for a CSV format, so what I want is to get those values, print them as multiple choices(checkboxes) and when I add a new "person", it gets the values selected and adds them to its respective Person table fields, that's no problem as its just processing the posted data, the issue is the form printing.

I'm doing this.

adding the entity for each

```php
use App\Entity\Language;
use App\Entity\Skill;
```

and in the PersonType for the forms

in the $builder I have this

```php
->add('language', EntityType::class, [
'class' => Language::class,
'choice_label' => 'language',
'multiple' => true,
'expanded' => true,
])
```

yet it keeps erroring that it cant find that label either, I get why, as in the "Person" form the language field is rendered as "person_language" not as "language" but if I change it to "language", The error then tells me it cant find the label "language" in the "Language" class.

is there a way to solve this issue without setting a One to Many relationship? (one person can have many languages)

in the case of having to use relationships, should the Many to One be on the other tables and not Person?
or if I go with One to Many, where should that bunch of relationships go? in Person? or how I go about that?

I'm not quite experienced with this part of doctrine, so let me explain a bit.

Person is the main table, then we have "language", "skills", "whatever1" and "whatever xxx" tables, person can have as many of "the other tables records associated to a Person record", but not the other way around. although a reverse search is not a bad feature to have, its not what I want, all I want is, when I have to add a new "person" into the database, I want to be able to choose from multiple selections, however it might come to be rendered on screen, the required values from the other entities as choices, but not the other way around.

so if I add a new Person, I need to be able (but not required to) select values from the multiple choice lists of the data from the other tables, but I MUST be able to add data to the other tables without affecting the table Person whatsoever at all nor need to select a person for them, the other tables are absolutely independent and closed, ONLY Person has to have relationships the other tables.

Cheers and thanks in advance,

Comment: You should show your Person entity mapping, at least the mapping for those fields. One thing you could do is set it as `'mapped' => false` and then in your controller, you set the property manually or leverage a formEvent.

Comment: I said in the question, I am not using relationships yet, I dont quite understand how should I go about them in doctrine.

I want to go with the unidirectional reference type, where the owner "Person" knows what it owns, but the owned "skills, address, whatever" do not know that they are owned.

so I can do $person->getSkills()/getAddress/getWhateverOtherThing()
not the other way around.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: I'll take a read, again, and hope to get something out of it. got about 30h to finish and all that I'm missing is this. if not ill have to do it some other way increidibly less efficient, by hand even maybe. :S

Comment: Your question gives a lot of unclear (to me) context and very few lines of code. Without your actual entity mapping it will be hard to help you. Also since you are using Symfony 5, I would recommend you use the `bin/console make:entity` command line to generate your entity and use `relation` as the property type for those, it will basically do it for you.

Comment: @JulienB.thanks for the effort, let me try a different way to explain.

I have a table called Person, it has several unique fields pertinent to just a single instance of a person record.

then I have other tables, for now, as its identical, lets use 2
Languages and Skills, each only contain 1 record per row (languages, english, spanish, german......etc, skills: programming, engineering, marketing.... etc) and others like it. but with a 2 tables example works as well as with 10.

I need to be able to add "languages" and "skills" without having to have a Person

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230695/discussion-between-jlchafardet-and-julien-b).